# Problema con recyclerView (Kotlin)

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

Al momento de crear un adaptador para un recyclerView no he podido hacer que reconozca el layout que le paso y los elementos que hay en el.

```
class adapter_wpHome(val mItems: List<content_wallp>, val context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_wpHome.viewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
        return viewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cv_list_wall, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = mItems.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(mItems[position])
    }

    class viewHolder( itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        fun bindItems ( item : content_wallp){

            Glide.with(itemView.context).load(item.path).into(itemView.img_wallp) // aqui no encuentra el elemento img_wallp en el layout

        }

    }
}
```

Vale la pena recalcar que tengo 3 aplicaciones mas donde he hecho de esta misma forma el adapter y todo funciona a la perfección, no se por que falla ya he revisado todos los otros adapter (mis otras apps) y son iguales !! 
No se en que este fallando, la app estaba toda en java y la estoy pasando a Kotlin, en esta clase utilice la opción de android studio que dice "De java a Kotlin", el adapter lo estoy creando en la misma clase que lo voy a utilizar, el data class igualmente y no es una activity, es un fragment, gracias por la colaboración.

Este es el error que muestra en consola
[image: Log, error]

Comment: Puedes por favor compartir el log donde se muestre el error?

Comment: @JhonFredyTrujilloOrtega he modificado la pregunta y agregue captura del error que muestra en el log, gracias

Comment: jmmmmm esta complicado, no veo cual pueda ser el error, si pueden subir el proyecto a un repo en github y compartirlo tal vez pueda encontar el error en mi ambiente de desarrollo

Comment: pues ahi te esta diciendo que ´img_wallp´  no se encuentra, ya verificaste si asi se llama en tu layout donde haces el item?

Comment: @MiguelOsorio si he verificado varias veces, incluso cambie el id por si estaba generando algún error y nada lo soluciona

Comment: @LeonardoHenao seria de mucha ayuda si pones el código completo de tu Adapter, para ver si estas importando lo necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Gracias a todos por la colaboración, publico mi solución de esta forma (en respuesta) ya que puede ser útil para algún otro usuario que tenga este mismo problema...

Después de revisar de "pies a cabeza" mis proyectos los cuales he pasado ya a Kotlin y que funcionan perfectamente, me encontré que en el `build gradle` del module app después de las dependencias en todos se agregaban

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

y por alguna razón que desconozco en este proyecto(el que me daba el error) no se habían agregado automáticamente las dos ultimas lineas, las agregue y todo funciono a la perfección... **Así que para mi, solucione este error agregando las siguientes lineas al** `build gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Despues de

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este error me ha pasado unas pocas veces, y la solucion la encontre [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848845/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin-compilation-error). Con la solucion 1 fue que corregi el problema.

Ve a `File -> Settings -> Compiler` y agrega los flags de `--stacktrace --debug` a los comandos del compilador.
Esto me paso debido a que en algun lugar tenia un error en el codigo, pero por algun motivo kotlin no me dice donde ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Al agregar los flags, vas a tener que leer un poco el log y con suerte encontraras en donde esta el fallo

Otra opcion es que declares las variables en la parte superior junto con el constructor, algo asi

```
class adapter_wpHome(val mItems: List<content_wallp>, val context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_wpHome.viewHolder>() {
    val img_wallp = view.img_wallp
    //etc etc
```

y en `bindItems` hacer uso de `img_wallp`